# How to hide the automatically HTML select element on change orientation in Ipad

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have created the one registration application form. The form is working fine except for Iphone and Ipad when we select the dropdown and close. Change the orientation select element automatically opens.

I also tried the solutions which mention in stack overflow question id: [iPad opens html select elements automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248945/ipad-opens-html-select-elements-automatically)

Please help me anyone and below and I'm sharing the code.

```js
$('.form-control').on("orientationchange", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.form-input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'SlatePro Bold';
  color: #565656;
}

.form-input input {
  border: 1px solid #2b5795;
  font-family: 'SlatePro Regular';
  width: 280px;
}

.enroll-form-input {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.enroll-form-input input[type=radio] {
  width: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
  <div class="form-input enroll-form-input">
    <label for="state">State</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state" placeholder="*Illinois" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="*State required">
      <option value="" selected disabled>*Illinois</option>
      <option value="1">State 1</option>
      <option value="">State 2</option>
      <option value="">State 3</option>
      <option value="">State 4</option>
    </select>
    <!-- <div class="invalid-feedback invalid-state">
    <div class="error-message">
      <div class="error-icon"><img src="images/error-icon.png" alt="error-icon" /> </div>
      <div class="error-content">*State required/div>
    </div>
    </div> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Auto opening of the select element on change of screen orientation in Ipad and iPhone with the below jquery code.

```js
$(window).on("orientationchange", function() { 
  $('select.form-control').blur();  
});
```